# Displaying $scope.array defined in controller back in html

Tags: angularjs, arrays, view, controller, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an $scope.array that looks like this in login.js:

```
[
{"Module Code": "module1", "marks": "40", "Recommendation": "test"},
{"Module Code": "module2", "marks": "50", "Recommendation": "exam"}
]
```

And I want to send this $scope.array back into the view to be displayed using ng-repeat but it does not work.

This is how my html file looks like:

```
<div ng-controller="loginCtrl">

<div ng-repeat="item in resultsArray">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="i in item">{{i}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is how I redirected from login.js to the html file:

```
$scope.resultsArray.push({
    "Module Code": $scope.moduleCode,
    "Marks" :$scope.marks,
    "Recommendation" :$scope.moduleRecommendation
})
$location.path('StudentGrades')
```

How do I get it to display in the html file ?

Comment: Can you please make a Plunker for this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by *"redirected from login.js"*? Is the `StudentGrades` path handled by a different controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this :

First of all make one array  like this :

```
$scope.resultsArray = [];
```

Then after that suppose your result array will look like this :

```
$scope.resultsArray = [{"ModuleCode": "module1", "marks": "40", "Recommendation": "test"},
{"Module Code": "module2", "marks": "50", "Recommendation": "exam"}]
```

Then after that in your view :

```
<div ng-controller="loginCtrl">

<div>
    <ul ng-repeat="item in resultsArray">
        <li>item.ModuleCode</li>
        <li>item.marks</li>
       <li>item.Recommendation</li>  
    </ul>
</div>
```

Let me know if this is not sufficient.

Comment: what is the for each loop for ?

Comment: what is the for each loop for ?

Comment: it is for to inject all your array to result array if you want, otherwise you can have directly let me know

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check and let me know , if you want anything else.

Comment: @purplewind : This is not what exact code which you can integrate and will work, there might be something you are not going with right, otherwise you have to put here your working plunker so that i can help much better.